org-mode habit with counter at header
Let's say I want to create a habit called "grandma visit" every week (+7d/10d), and I want it to have a counter at the title, so every time I complete the habit, it will go up a number. So first week it will be "grandma visit 01", then next week when I hit done, it will be "grandma visit 02" and so on.
How would you do such a thing?

Instead of modifying the headline, I would suggest you maintain a property instead. It's what properties are for and there is programming support for them, so you avoid the ad-hoc nature of one-off solutions - plus it's hidden  from view in general, but easily accessible by just pressing a TAB on the properties drawer.

That's a good idea, but then I don't see it on my agenda, which is what I was hoping to get. In a quick glimpse I know what event # it is. Though, tabbing into it to take a look is not so hard... I will look into your link - thank you!

You can turn on follow mode in the agenda (with F) which shows the current agenda item in the context of its file in the other window, but you still have to go there and press TAB to open the property drawer, which might be a pain. But you may be able to add the property value to what is shown in the agenda in a different way (perhaps through org-agenda-prefix-format) - untested and not well thought-out ATM, but I think it's a possibility.

Here's a solution along the lines of my comments: instead of modifying the headline, we modify a property; that's what properties are for and there is programming support for them, so you avoid the ad-hoc nature of one-off solutions. We then arrange that the agenda print the value of the property (if present).
Short version:
Add the following to your init file:
(defun my/increment-visits-propval-maybe ()
  (let ((pval (org-entry-get nil "VISITS")))
    (when (and (string= org-state "DONE")
               pval)
               (org-entry-put nil "VISITS" (number-to-string (1+ (string-to-number pval)))))))

(with-eval-after-load 'org
   (add-to-list 'org-after-todo-state-change-hook #'my/increment-visits-propval-maybe))

(defun my/visits-maybe ()
  (let ((visits (org-entry-get nil "VISITS")))
    (if visits
        (format "visits: %s" visits)
      "")))

(with-eval-after-load 'org-agenda
   (setcdr (assq 'agenda org-agenda-prefix-format)
             " %i %-12:c%?-12t% s%?-12(my/visits-maybe)"))

Then add the VISITS property with the initial value of 0 to your Grandma visit entry: with point in that entry, say C-c C-x p VISITS RET 0 RET (the key sequence C-c C-x p is bound to org-set-property in the Org mode keymap).
You'll need to restart your emacs for the modified init file to be loaded.
See the longer version for some explanations.

Longer version:
To modify the property (let's call it VISITS), we write a function that will be called from the org-after-todo-state-change-hook. The function needs to check that it's the "correct" state change (i.e. we changed the state to DONE) and that the entry contains a VISITS property already. It will then retrieve the current value, increment it and store the incremented value back into the property. Here's the function:
(defun my/increment-visits-propval-maybe ()
  (let ((pval (org-entry-get nil "VISITS")))
    (when (and (string= org-state "DONE")
               pval)
               (org-entry-put nil "VISITS" (number-to-string (1+ (string-to-number pval)))))))

and we add it to the hook with this:
(add-to-list 'org-after-todo-state-change-hook #'my/increment-visits-propval-maybe)

The function checks for the right context:

org-state is a variable that Org maintains for us and makes available to functions in the hook (see the hook's doc string with C-h v org-after-todo-state-change-hook) - the "right" context means that it should have the value "DONE".

the entry whose state we are changing must have a VISITS property (assumed to be an integer if present).


You can check this much by manually adding the property (with value 0) to your grandma visit entry with C-c C-x p VISITS RET 0 RET; then change its state to DONE: every time you do that, the value of VISITS gets incremented by 1.

Now that the accounting is set up, we need to set up the reporting. Since you want to see the visits in the agenda, we'll write a function that returns the desired string based on the property value and have the agenda call it by modifying org-agenda-prefix-format.
First the function:
(defun my/visits-maybe ()
  (let ((visits (org-entry-get nil "VISITS")))
    (if visits
        (format "visits: %s" visits)
      "")))

If the agenda entry has a VISITS property, we return the string "visits: N" where N is the value of the property. If not, we return the empty string.
Next, we'll modify the format, but first we'll get its original value so that you can see what is changed:
;;; get the value of the agenda part of the variable `agenda-prefix-format'

(assq 'agenda org-agenda-prefix-format) ==> (agenda . " %i %-12:c%?-12t% s") 

;;; now modify the cdr of that part, i.e. the format string
(setcdr (assq 'agenda org-agenda-prefix-format)
          " %i %-12:c%?-12t% s%?-12(my/visits-maybe)")

You'll need to study the doc string of org-agenda-prefix-format if you want to understand the voodoo here. Briefly, there are four parts (agenda, todo, tags, search) corresponding to each kind of agenda you can use when you select from the agenda dispatcher with a key (a, t, m or s). I only change the weekly agenda prefix format here. I got the new format format  by adding the %?-12(my/visits-maybe) part at the end of the original format. That will print the value that is returned from calling my/visits-maybe (but, because of the ?, not if it is the empty string) in a 12-char wide field padded with spaces on the right (that's the -12).
When you view the weekly agenda with C-c a a (assuming you have followed the suggestion in the documentation about binding C-c a to org-agenda), your grandma visit entries should be shown something like this:
  ...
  repeating:   8:45-9:45  visits: 1   TODO Grandma visit
  ...

Of course, the category repeating is going to be different in your case, as well as the time (which may not be there at all, depending on what your Grandma visit entry looks like).
